# SQL Sharepoint Integration using oData connector with SSIS

Tags: sharepoint, ssis, odata, ssis-2012

SSIS Sharepoint Connection using OData connector. I was able to connect to Sharepoint site fine and was able to see the data thru preview and all.. but when i execute the task i get below error.

[OData Source [2]] Error: The OData Source was unable to process the data. Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Task: OData as Source(with SP connection information) and OLE DB Destination.

Comment: I don't get any response from web site at all..

Answer (score 0):

I worked with this SharePoint connector a couple of years ago and recall it being somewhat tricky to set up.  Check the following link to see if you may have left out any steps.

> http://dataqueen.unlimitedviz.com/2011/06/how-to-use-a-sharepoint-list-as-a-data-source-in-your-ssis-package/

Also, I remember that by default the SharePoint connector mapped every column, most of which were not needed.  This resulted in a memory limitation and was resolved by removing the mappings not needed.

Comment: I never had any problems with Sharepoint adapters from codeplex but for somereason we are supposed to use oData connector for integration and that's where i have problems.